# How programatically read the content of html page using that page URL in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How programatically read the content of html page using that page URL in asp.net ?
For Example i need to read the content of my facebook url eg:https://www.facebook.com/mano1822

Comment: Others have found luck with [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), but I would suggest you post what it is that you've tried so far and how it has failed.

Comment: If you need only html: use WebClient. If you need more customizations: HttpWebRequest. If you need also parse html(select some data): htmlagilitypack. Btw, I think that getting facebook page, isn't trivial and can be tricky. P.S.: also look to Fiddler, to see web traffic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to make an HTTP request to the respective URL and parse the response. I would suggest using [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/456dfw4f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  as reference, which has nice examples too.

EDIT:
The code posted below is from the specific post:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://testserver/testpage");

//If the target server requires authentication, you have to give some credentials in
//your request object. The way you pass these credentials depends on the authentication
//mechanism of the server...

WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream ();
//use dataStream to read data from the server

response.Close();`
```

Hope I helped!

Comment: link only answers are frowned upon.  perhaps adding some code from your link would improve this post.

Comment: @paqogomez I suppose you are right. A code snippet would be helpful.

Comment: @PantelisNatsiavas. . Yes code works fine. . it helped me lot. .:)